# Chrome notification not working

Tags: google-chrome-extension, push-notification

I have code which works under Windows 7 Chrome correctly, but not in Ubuntu Chrome.

```
var opt = {
type: "list",
title: "Primary Title",
message: "Primary message to display",
iconUrl: "../icon.png",
items: [{ title: "Item1", message: "This is item 1."},
    { title: "Item2", message: "This is item 2."},
    { title: "Item3", message: "This is item 3."}]
}
chrome.notifications.create(new Date().getTime().toString(), opt, function() {});
```

In Ubuntu it looks like basic notification. What's wrong with it? Maybe Ubuntu's Chrome not support such notifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. Linux version of Chrome does not support the "Rich" notifications yet, and falls back to default notifications.

Corresponding bug is (loosely) [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=291485), and is pending major changes in Chrome regarding Aura, so don't expect it soon.